# IOS Swift 3 FCM Token Generates invaid Token

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, swift3

I have a IOS app that generates a FCM token however when we send a push notification it shows below result.

```
{"multicast_id":7286183653567149258,"success":0,"failure":3,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"error":"InvalidRegistration"},{"error":"InvalidRegistration"},{"error":"InvalidRegistration"}]}Array{"multicast_id":7286183653567149258,"success":0,"failure":3,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"error":"InvalidRegistration"},{"error":"InvalidRegistration"},{"error":"InvalidRegistration"}]}
```

When I use Firebase Cloud Messaging console to send a test push notification it does deliver to the device.

My swift code is:

```
import UIKit
import IQKeyboardManagerSwift
import Firebase
import FirebaseMessaging
import FirebaseInstanceID
import UserNotifications
import Alamofire
import FirebaseAuth

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?
    var count:Int = 0

    let gcmMessageIDKey = "gcm.message_id"

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        IQKeyboardManager.sharedManager().enable = true

      FIRApp.configure()

        application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0

        count = 0


        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
            options: authOptions) {_,_ in }
            // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
        } else {
            let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
                UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
            application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
        }
        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

        //application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
        //NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.tokenRefreshNotification), name: .firbaseInstanceIDTokenRefresh, object: nil) 
        return true
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
        let token = deviceToken.map { String(format: "%02.2hhx", $0) }.joined()
        FIRInstanceID.instanceID().setAPNSToken(deviceToken as Data, type: FIRInstanceIDAPNSTokenType.prod)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please server key set to backend site.

Comment: Yes This one set on backend side.and also check FCM Token get and send to your server.

Comment: token is : da3bd4ff02b6eb4bc6ec5fc1c3211ae6f567e7b6446dc2ba86fd9f9d9964c0ac

Comment: @bozcadercharity You should remove the server key. Credentials are kind not meant to be posted in public. this can be misused!

Comment: Yes you can send notification on this FCM Token from backend side.

Comment: I did and it shows the error {"multicast_id":7286183653567149258,"success":0,"failure":3,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"error":"InvalidRegistration"},{"error":"InvalidRegistration"},{"error":"InvalidRegistration"}]}Array{"multicast_id":7286183653567149258,"success":0,"failure":3,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"error":"InvalidRegistration"},{"error":"InvalidRegistration"},{"error":"InvalidRegistration"}]}

Answer (score 0):

```
extension AppDelegate : MessagingDelegate {
      func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didRefreshRegistrationToken fcmToken: String) {
                if let refreshedToken = InstanceID.instanceID().token() {
                    print("InstanceID token : \(refreshedToken)")
                       self.updateFIRKey(tokenVal: devTkn)  // method to update devicetoken
                }
      }
}
```

Comment: i have updated the answer with MessagingDelegate,
pls let me know if it working or not

Comment: Use of undeclared type 'MessagingDelegate'

Comment: please import Firebase

Comment: I have import Firebase command however it still generates that error

Comment: import UIKit
import IQKeyboardManagerSwift
import Firebase
import FirebaseMessaging
import FirebaseInstanceID
import UserNotifications
import Alamofire
import FirebaseAuth

Comment: please check this link
https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-ios/blob/master/messaging/MessagingExampleSwift/AppDelegate.swift

Comment: Hi unfortunately it didnt. I still have same problems

Comment: okay,then remove all pods and install it again,may be your fire base pods have some issues